# WP Как в произвольные поля записать количество знаков в статье?

Tags: php, wordpress

Подскажите как для всех постов в Wordpress создать переменную в произвольных полях $word_count

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

значение которой бы равнялось количеству знаков в посте которое б считалось по вот такой формуле ?

```
  function str_word_count_utf8($str) {
       $a = preg_split('/\W+/u', $str, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
        return count($a);
   }

$word_count = str_word_count_utf8(strip_tags($content));
```

при перезаписи статьии количество знаков в переменной должно пересчитываться.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно прицепится на action сохранения поста и сохранять или обновлять необходимые мета данные

```
add_action( 'save_post', 'add_word_count' );

function add_word_count( $post_id ) {

    if ( defined( 'DOING_AUTOSAVE' ) && DOING_AUTOSAVE ) {
        return;
    }

    update_post_meta( $post_id, 'word_count', str_word_count_utf8( $_POST['post_content'] ) );
}
```

получить значение мета поля можно вот

```
get_post_meta( $post_id, 'word_count', true )
```

где $post_id - id нужного поста

Comment: Ответ правильный, но `verify_nonce` и `current_user_can` здесь излишни - эти действия выполняются ядром до вызова хука `save_post`.

Comment: @KAGGDesign спасибо, исправил

Comment: Плюсанул ответ.

Comment: Спасибо, работает. Единственное, не могу понять, почему когда идет обновление поста Update переменная слетает в 0 / При сохранении все ок

Comment: @BlackStar1991возможно нет парамета post_content я думаю вам нужно добавить проверку на существование это парамерта в глобальной переменной перед сохранием мета данных
    if ( ! isset( $_POST['post_content']) ) {
        return;
    }

Comment: @Darth KYL Проверку добавил, но это не помогло, ещё вылетел баг - если данный запрос на получение результата get_post_meta( $post_id, 'word_count', true ); для одного и того же поста встречается дважды на странице, то выдает ошибку на втором мыводе / Хотя var_dump($word_count); ответ показывает